# What happens if you plug an iPod into a USBC iPad?

Tags: ipad, itunes, ipod

What happens if you plug an iPod into a USBC iPad?

Some people don't have laptops. Could they use their USBC iPads to manage their more portable music players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing bad happens - i.e. the units won't blow up or anything like that.

But you will not be able to manage the iPod from the iPad, so you cannot sync an iPod from an iPad.